# The value of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}$

Tags: limits

Let
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}$$
exists.

**What are the value of the limitation and $a$**

**My attempt**
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}=0$$

Let $l=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}$, if $l\neq0$,then we have,
$$\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\leq|\sin((n+1)a)|+|\sin(na)|\leq2$$
$l\leq2$, but

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin(na)-\sin((n-1)a)\right]}$$

so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin((n-1)a)\right]}=2l$$
we get,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin((n-k)a)\right]}=kl$$
$\exists k\in\mathbb{N},kl>2$, so $l=0$.

But I don't know the value of $a$, so I want to get some help.

Thanks

Comment: Notice how you said "if $l \neq 0$ then we have". Then you conclude $l=0$

Comment: Use the difference of sines formula to write $\sin A -  \sin B$ as a product of a sine and a cosine of two other quantities.

Comment: @Hugh What do you mean?

Comment: The argument works if you assume $l>0$ and you should modify it for the case $l<0$ (not difficult).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
L
&= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[\sin((n+1)a)-\sin(na)\right]}
= \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\left[2\cos\left(na+\frac a2\right)\sin\left(\frac a2\right)\right]} \\
& = 2\sin \left(\frac a2\right)\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\cos\left(\frac a2+na\right)}.
\end{align}
Hence, $a=k\pi, k\in \mathbb Z$ and $L=0$.

Comment: With $a = 2 \pi$ and $n = 1$ we have $\cos\left( \frac{a}{2} + n a \right) = \cos(3 \pi) \neq 0$, so why is the limit zero?

Comment: @Viktor Glombik, because for $a=2\pi$, the sine is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$$

Comment: $a=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$?